# How to store multiple strings in list in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have this `ListOfCoordinates` list with 5 tuples (image below), with each index corresponding to the coordinates of two regions of the brain.

[image]

I also have this variable named `brain_areas_ROIs`, which is a dictionary (image below) with the names of all possible brain regions.

[image]

So I want to store in a dictionary the respective brain regions for all the pairs of coordinates obtained,  like `dict = {0: 'Frontal_Med_Orb_L', 'Frontal_Sup_Medial_L', 1: 'Frontal_Med_Orb_R', 'Frontal_Sup_Medial_L'}`, so on and so on.

I'm really lost at this... any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected result? Also - don't post images, we cannot copy and paste it.

Comment: Just edited! Sorry for the images, it was the first option that occurred to me to demonstrate the variables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does something like this work? I was not sure exactly what kind of variable you wanted. The two variables I used are shortened examples that you can fill with your data.

```
def main():
    ListOfCoordinates = [
        (2, 4),
        (1, 5),
        (6, 3),
        (7, 0)
    ]

    brain_areas_ROIs = {
        0: "Precentral_L",
        1: "Precentral_R",
        2: "Frontal_Sup_L",
        3: "Frontal_Sup_R",
        4: "Frontal_Sup_Orb_L",
        5: "Frontal_Sup_Orb_R",
        6: "Frontal_Mid_L",
        7: "Frontal_Mid_L"
    }

    print(brain_thing(ListOfCoordinates, brain_areas_ROIs))


def brain_thing(coordinates: list, brain_pos: dict) -> list:
    brain_list = []

    for coordinate in coordinates:
        brain_list.append((brain_pos[coordinate[0]], brain_pos[coordinate[1]]))

    return brain_list
```

Comment: It's exactly that!! Thank you so much Caleb!!